# How can I translate SORT BY, COMPARE and SHOW text to dutch?

Tags: language

I want to know how I can change the text from the "compare", "sort by" and "show". I want to translate them to Dutch. Everything else is translated but some parts are not.

I'm really new to Magento...

thx for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To translate this and other items:

1. Go to `System->Configuration->Developer`
2. Under `Translate inline` set to `Yes`
3. Go to `System->Cache Management` disable `Translations`
4. Go to your frontend and click the word(s) you wish to translate - enter their translations
5. Go to `System->Configuration->Developer`
6. Under `Translate inline` set to `No`

Verify the translation has taken effect.

Answer (score 2):

you also can edit the csv files under app/locale/

The English locales you find in app/locale/en_US, the Dutch are in app/locale/nl_NL.

If the csv does not exist in nl_NL, you can copy the English csv to the Dutch and modify it there.

In each line, the strings before the commas are the keys (don't edit them), the strings after are the translations for your language.

Comment: The CSV exists but when I search for the english text, nothing is found in the csv.